# PHPMailer - Sending emails via SMTP & Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using a [PHPMailer Form found here.](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form)

The example from the website download is "Contact-3" to send SMTP emails via gmail using PHPMailer within a Bootstrap theme.  When I use "Contact-1" it works perfectly to my hosted domain email address but with the SMTP version to a gmail address the contact form doesn't submit.

Out of the code below, I changed the following lines to added my gmail address and gmail password:

```
$sendToEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$smtpUsername = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$smtpPassword = 'MyPassword';
```

Any help on making this work with the given info would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

```
<?php
/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
AND ALSO SMTP TO SEND THE EMAILS
*/

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'demo@domain.com';
$fromName = 'Demo contact form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$sendToName = 'Demo contact form';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// smtp credentials and server

$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$smtpUsername = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$smtpPassword = 'MyPassword';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name','email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back 
to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again 
later';

/*
*  LET'S DO THE SENDING
*/

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by 
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

$emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
$emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
    }
}
$emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
$emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a nice day,<br>Best,<br>Ondrej</p>";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
$mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by 
simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
$mail->addReplyTo($from);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $emailTextHtml;
$mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version 
of the HTML email, very handy


$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
$mail->Host = gethostbyname($smtpHost);

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP 
submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = $smtpHost;

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = $smtpPassword;


if(!$mail->send()) {
    throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
// $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: If something doesn't work, then leaving debugging disabled is not the best path to resolve it. The gmail password isn't usually the SMTP password.

Comment: [Sending email fails when two factor authentication is on for Gmail](//stackoverflow.com/q/26736062)

Comment: Thanks but I already had the two step authentication off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you will be getting a certificate verification error due to your use of `gethostbyname`. That call is a workaround for a badly configured network, and it does not combine with SMTP+STARTTLS because it will always cause a name mismatch. Try commenting out that line and using `smtp.gmail.com` For the host name instead.

Use the gmail examples provided with PHPMailer as a reference, and update to the latest version of PHPMailer.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it going yet but I appreciate this help, thanks!